# Design an algorithm for guessing a card number

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am making a card guessing game.there are 100 cards place in 10rows and 10 columns each card with a number and user have to find a number he is thinking of. i want to devise an algorithm to determine whether a given number is written on one of the cards by turning up less than 20 cards.I hav created the buttons dynamically, now im having hard time making a logic to search through them.This is my code.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int rememberlast = 0, move = 0;
        object savelastobject;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int sizee = 50, where = 0;
            this.Height = 0;
            this.Width = 0;
            var generatedNum = new List<int>();
            var random = new Random();

            while (generatedNum.Count < 100)
            {
                var tempo = random.Next(0, 100);

                if (generatedNum.Contains(tempo)) continue;
                generatedNum.Add(tempo);
            }
            char[] text2 = text.ToCharArray();
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
                {
                    Button ta = new Button();
                    ta.Name = x.ToString()+y.ToString();
                    ta.Width = sizee;
                    ta.Height = sizee;
                    ta.Tag = generatedNum[where];

                    where++;
                    ta.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    ta.Location = new Point(70 * y, 70 * x);
                    Controls.Add(ta);
                    ta.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);

                    this.Width += 90 * x / 13;
                    this.Height += 90 * x / 8;
                }
            }
        }
        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Control me = (Control)sender;

                rememberlast = int.Parse(me.Tag.ToString());
                savelastobject = me;
                me.Text = me.Tag.ToString();
                me.Enabled = true;
                me.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                move++;
                label2.Text = move.ToString();

                me.Enabled = true;
                me.Text = me.Tag.ToString();
                me.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                me.Refresh();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                if (move == 20)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Total Moves Consumed");
                    Application.Restart();
                }
                if (me.Tag.ToString() == textBox1.Text)
                {
                    //Control him = (Control)savelastobject;
                    //him.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                    me.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                    MessageBox.Show("You Win");
                    Application.Restart();
                }
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: Do a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Comment: If you need 100 numbers arranged randomly, then the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) will work better than picking a random number and seeing if it has already been used.

Comment: If you have the 100 numbers arranged *at random*, it is possible that you will have to examine 99 cards to determine where the selected number is.

Comment: You need some way to narrow down the number of options, simply asking "is this your card?", can take up to 99 cards and can be expected to require something like 50 cards. You need something like "higher or lower", "up, down, left or right" in order to allow for faster finding of the desired card.

Comment: @radarbob i hav tried to implement binary search tree but i dont know how to iterate it from box to box

Comment: @JohnnyMopp i hav to find the desire card in less than 20 moves

Comment: @Sami, let me ask you something. Shuffle a deck of cards and lay them on the table. Can you, in less than 20 moves, select 4 of hearts? No, because that is the point of randomness.

Comment: @Sami, I misunderstood the problem. As other comments say, if the card deck is not in order - i.e. its in random order - then there is no systematic way of finding "ace of spades" for example.